# How can I get full output error if subprocess.run failed?

Tags: python, bash

For example I'm trying to run some bash command from python:

```
from subprocess import run

command = f'ffmpeg -y -i "{video_path}" "{frames_path}/%d.png"'
run(command, shell=True, check=True)
```

but if it fails I just get `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'ffmpeg ...' returned non-zero exit status 127.` how can I get full ffmpeg error message?

Comment: I would probably start with a review of [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). You need (a) to instruct `subprocess.run` to capture the output in which you are interested, and then (b) inspect the value returned by `run` to retrieve the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `check=True` kwarg that's causing it to throw a `CalledProcessError`. Just remove `check=True`, and it will stop throwing the error. If you want to print the STDERR printed by ffmpeg, you can use `capture_output=True`. Then, the resulting `CompletedProcess` object will have a `.stderr` member that contains the STDERR of your command, encoded as a bytes-like string. Use `str.decode()` to turn it into a normal string:

```py
from subprocess import run

command = f'ffmpeg -y -i "{video_path}" "{frames_path}/%d.png"'
proc = run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True)
out = proc.stdout.decode() # stores the output of stdout
err = proc.stderr.decode() # stores the output of stderr
print(err)
```